# How to label a integer column based on a conditional statement in R

Tags: if-statement, label

I want to label this vector `C` into either `[1] HY HY HY HY LY HY` (2 levels) or vice versa `[1] LY LY LY LY HY LY` (2 levels) based on a condition I specified using `factor`.

For example,

```
C <- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1)

ifelse(50 > 100,
    factor(C, labels = c('HY','LY')),
    factor(C, labels = c('LY','HY')))
```

This prints out `[1] 1` rather than my expectation.

But `factor(C, labels = c('LY','HY'))` works fine. Why is that?

Then I did a test by taking out `factor`, but it still doesn't give me `'LY' 'HY'`.

```
ifelse(50 > 100,
        c('HY','LY'),
        c('LY','HY'))
[1] "LY"
```

Another option I can think of is to change the vector into characters like this and then change it to `factor`. In either case, it should give me a vector, not a value.

```
ifelse(50 > 100,
        ifelse(C==1, 'HY', 'LY'),
        ifelse(C==1, 'LY', 'HY'))
[1] "LY"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out `ifelse` is like a `for` loop that accepts a vector input and prints out a vector of the same length, i.e. `50>100` prints out `FALSE` of the length 1 and so as the output.

When I use `if` instead of `ifelse`, the problem solved.

```
if(50>100){
     ifelse(C==1, 'HY', 'LY')
 } else {
     ifelse(C==1, 'LY', 'HY')
 }

[1] "LY" "LY" "LY" "LY" "HY" "LY"
```